# Because of scientific notation, data is automatically converted to numeric in importation

Tags: excel, import-from-excel, scientific-notation

I have some registers like 1D-2, 1E-2, 1F-3, and so on in a system.

When exporting a .csv from the system, and reading the file in excel the rows with "E" in the name are automacally converted to number due the scientific notation, e.g., 1E-1 became 0.1, with no possibility of returning the data to the original format, even converting to text.

Is it possible to avoid this conversion when importing my.csv? Because I am unable to alter my original data pattern.

Comment: What are you using for the import? Power Query?

Comment: Do not just open it.  You will need to Import it and use the wizard or power query to dictate the schema of that column as text.